# Datetime returns wrong time

Tags: php, datetime

```
$a=new DateTime();
echo $a->format('d-m-y H:i');
```

This prints me `23-10-14 23:18` but the problem is that curently for me the time is 24/10/14 00:18, which is one hour later. Why is it happening like this and how to fix it?

Comment: different timezone on server / php installation?

Comment: See PHP's [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: I did `date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get());` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: ^ lol "set the default timezone to whatever the current default timezone is" I can't stop laughing

Comment: That just sets the timezone to the value to which it is already set. You may need to specify your specific timezone (e.g. `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`).

Comment: You could also specify a timezone for the DateTime function, that is: `$a = new DateTime(NULL, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));`

Comment: I see, thought `get` would return my curent timezone.

Comment: It might be getting the value that is set in your php.ini file. Check the [order of preference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) for `get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just internet stalked you, looks like you need:

`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');`